# Ubuntu hosts: testing package upgrades and delay

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, updates, delay

I'm managing eleven ubuntu hosts and want to introduce regular updates (mainly for security). One of them is my developing and testing host.

Is the following good practice?

- run `sudo apt update -y` on a certain day each month on each pc
- run `sudo apt upgrade -y` directly afterwards on the testing host
- run `sudo apt upgrade -y` a week later on the other machines

This allows for me to test whether the updates broke something or created some other failures. I've looked a bit at `unattended-upgrades` but I did not find a way to implement the delay.

Comment: Probably you may do on the other machines `sudo apt upgrade -y --download-only`. Or better you can elect one of the others as a _local repository_ and download only there the files. Then, a week after, you can download the packages from that local repository and not from internet...

Comment: Very nice idea, thank you

Comment: ...moreover you should use a _stable_ distribution and if you do not have any special needs a LTS one. Ps> Welcome on SuperUser